# What is causing double rows, and how to fix when constrained by code

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I'm "tapping in" to some php code, trying to adhere to my shopping cart's "best practices" of not over-writing core code.  So I'm limited on how I can insert code and where.  This is the resulting SQL being executed:

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    b.*, a.*
    FROM `product` a
    LEFT JOIN `product_lang` b ON (b.`id_product` = a.`id_product` AND b.`id_lang` = 1 AND b.`id_shop` = 1)
     INNER JOIN product_shop product_shop
ON (product_shop.id_product = a.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)  JOIN `category_lang` cl ON (cl.id_category = a.id_category_default) 
    WHERE 1  AND cl.name <> "Archives" AND a.id_product IN (
    SELECT p.id_product
    FROM `product` p
     LEFT 
    JOIN stock_available stock
    ON (stock.id_product = p.id_product AND stock.id_shop = 1  AND stock.id_shop_group = 0  )
    WHERE p.id_product NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT(id_product)
        FROM `product_attribute`
    )
    AND IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) <= 0
)
    ORDER BY a.`id_product` DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

The code I'm responsible for in there is:

```
JOIN `category_lang` cl ON (cl.id_category = a.id_category_default)
```

And

```
 AND cl.name <> "Archives"
```

I have no say in where that is inserted.

I actually get the results I'm looking for... only twice.  Each record is returned in duplicate.

Comment: Can't you just https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html them :)

Comment: Not without some example I can't.  That's new to me.  But it appears that has to go in the SELECT section, which I can't insert into.  I can pile a JOIN on and I can add to the WHERE.  That's about it.

Comment: Ok, try setting `GROUP BY a.id_product` before `ORDER BY` and check if you get the desired result. You can read about group by from the link I posted above ^^'

Comment: Did that.  It returns no duplicates, but it no longer respects my WHERE condition.  When I view resulting code, it inserts the GROUP BY after *my* where statement, but before the "AND a.id_product IN"

Comment: I figured out how to get it where you said.  Results same (no dups, but ignores where)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you have in these tables, but run your query without the `group by` we added, then see what actually "duplicates", because this happens when you have two unique rows which are related to a single one from another table. Just take a look which column is duplicated in your results and group by that column.

Comment: I made a mistake.  Your group by solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we found is [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) the column that "duplicates", which is caused by the joins you have.

```
GROUP BY a.id_product
ORDER BY a.`id_product` DESC LIMIT 0,50
```